# What's wrong with my beta reduction of pred c_0 on Church numerals?

Tags: lambda-calculus, church-numerals

I'm trying to calculate $\text{pred}\, c_0$, where $\text{pred}$ is the previous church encoded number and $c_0$ is the number $0$ ($\lambda s. \lambda z. z$).

The formula for $\text{pred}$ is $\lambda n. \lambda s. \lambda z. n (\lambda g. \lambda h. h (g s))(\lambda u.z)(\lambda v.v)$

My $\beta$ reduction looks like this so far (I've underlined the function and the applied parameter)

$$
\text{pred}\, c_0 \to \lambda s. \lambda z. c_0 \underline{(\lambda g. \lambda h. h (g s))}\text{ }\underline{(\lambda u.z)}(\lambda v.v) \to $$

$$\lambda s. \lambda z. c_0 (\lambda h. h (\underline{(\lambda u.z)}\text{ } \underline{s}))(\lambda v.v) \to$$

$$\lambda s. \lambda z. c_0 \underline{(\lambda h. h z)}\text{ }\underline{(\lambda v.v)} \to$$

$$\lambda s. \lambda z. \underline{c_0}\text{ } \underline{z} \to$$

$$\lambda s. \lambda z. (???)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \mathrm{pred}\, c_0 \to \lambda s. \lambda z. c_0 \underline{(\lambda g. \lambda h. h (g s))} \; \underline{(\lambda u.z)}(\lambda v.v) $$

Nope, that's not a redex.

You have a term of the form $c_0 M N P$. That's $c_0 M N$ applied to $P$. It could be parenthesised as $((c_0 M) N) P$. This is [how lambda calculus encodes functions with multiple arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying): by applying the function to one argument, and then applying the result to the next argument, and so on. Since this construction is very common, parentheses are omitted: function application associates to the left.

Once you expand the abbreviations, there is only one redex in $\mathrm{pred}\,c_o$, which is $(\lambda n. []) c_0$. This is very intuitive: $\mathrm{pred}$ is a function that takes a numeral as an argument, and the first thing you to to kick off the calculation is to apply the function to the numeral.

Comment: I see... So what I did was, instead of using $M$ as a parameter of the function $c0$, I used $c0$'s parameter $N$ as a parameter of $M$, which was actually just a parameter of $c0$? I basically applied a parameter to a parameter? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Clash Yes, the term is $c_0 M N P$, i.e. $((c_0 M)N)P$, and you calculated $(M N)$ which doesn't occur as a subterm.

Comment: How come if it's $c_2$ instead of $c_0$ the redex is then $\mathrm{pred}\, c_2 \to \lambda s. \lambda z.  \underline{c_2(\lambda g. \lambda h. h (g s))} \; \underline{(\lambda u.z)}(\lambda v.v)$?

Comment: @Clash That's the second redex, after reducing the $\lambda n. …$ that appears when you replace pred by its definition.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? I just replaced $c_0$ with $c_2$ from the first equation. However the first equation the redex is processed like this $
\text{pred} c_0 \to \lambda s. \lambda z. \underline{c_0} \underline{(\lambda g. \lambda h. h (g s))}\text{ }\(\lambda u.z)(\lambda v.v) \to $

Comment: That's after the first step of beta reduction. The second step would be to apply $c_0$ (or $c_2$) to $\lambda g. \lambda h. h(g s)$.

Comment: Yes, exactly, but when using $c_2$ my book applies $c_2(\lambda g.\lambda h. h (gs))$ to $\lambda u. z$ as the second step. Is this also valid? I made a picture of the book: http://i.imgur.com/FFY8uXs.jpg. Do you see how it changed which redex is being used on the 2nd step (after reducing $\lambda n$) and the only difference is if it's $c_0$ or $c_2$? Or am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: Alright, I understand it now. The underlines on $\text{pred} c_2$ were actually "wrong" (they are not the ones that were actually evaluated, but he is instead doing two reductions at once)